# Oracle Data Provider for Entity Framework Case Insensitivity

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, entity-framework

I have been searching for a way to make Case Insensitive searches through Entity Framework to Oracle using Oracles Entity Framework adapter for some time now without luck.

I have found some approaches but don't feel as though any are a good solution for my requirements.

One solution is to use the .ToUpper on both the database column and also the parameter, but I have read there could be some serious speed issues as well as the SQL that comes through can be very messy.

The other solution was to set the oracle database to a LINGUISTIC compare, however we may not have the ability to set this when we go to production.

When I tried using the .Equals() overload for currentCulutreCaseInsentive I received an error.

Does anyone know of any best practices for this? or a good solution to return case intensive search results?

Thanks

Comment: The best that you can do is to check if the ToUpper on the linq query app is applied in the Oracle query in a simple, natural way. It should do it. With SQL Server there are many string methods that are perfectly converted to T-SQL, i.e. StartsWith("x") is transformed into a LIKE 'x%' in the query. So don't rely on "what people say" but on "what you check".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stuck to the ToUpper commands on both sides as suggested by JotaBe

Comment: I would still love to get a better answer, since querying in Oracle SQL Developer does not require table or column names to be cased correctly.